# Unable to call contract function because Metamask doesn't pop up though it's connected to Remix

Tags: contract-development, remix, metamask, contract-deployment, external-function

I've been having this issue for a while. Whenever I try calling a function or deploy a contract using Remix, the Metamask doesn't pop-up, even though if Metamask is connected to Remix. The only thing that happens is that there is a pop-up from Remix saying:

"Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
execution reverted"

And down at the console, it says:
"transact to Force.transfer pending ..."

I think there is no connection with gas estimation as the Remix pop-up says:
It seems like it just chooses when it'll work and when it won't work.

The contract THIS TIME is the one below:
The error occurs independent of the contract I'm trying to deploy.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract King {

  address king;
  uint public prize;
  address public owner;

  constructor() payable {
    owner = msg.sender;  
    king = msg.sender;
    prize = msg.value;
  }

  receive() external payable {
    require(msg.value >= prize || msg.sender == owner);
    payable(king).transfer(msg.value);
    king = msg.sender;
    prize = msg.value;
  }

  function _king() public view returns (address) {
    return king;
  }
}

contract Force {

    function transfer(address _to) external payable {
        payable(_to).transfer(msg.value);
    } 
}

contract Attack {
    Force force;

    constructor(Force _force) {
        force = Force(_force);
    }

    function attack() public payable {
        // You can simply break the game by sending ether so that
        // the game balance >= 7 ether

        // cast address to payable
        //See: https://solidity-by-example.org/hacks/self-destruct/ to understand self-destruct
        address payable addr = payable(address(force));
        selfdestruct(addr);
    }
}
```

I tried cleaning up the cookies, but it still didn't work.
I just want to be able to interacte with contracts, since I'm going through CTF's

**Screenshot of Remix pop-up:**
[image]

**Screenshot of Remix console:**
[image]

**Screenshot of account activity on Metamask**
[image]

Comment: Ensure you got enough funds for that transaction to go through.

Comment: Yes, I do have enough funds